# What is the keyboard shortcut for dropdown that appears when you paste text?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2011

Is there a keyboard shortcut to activate the dropdown that appears when you paste text in Word 2011 for Mac? (Equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in Word 2007 on Windows, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Word 2010 on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in Word for Mac 2011 you can press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to bring up the paste options down menu before inserting the content.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I may well end up using this. However, it does have a couple of disadvantages:
1) if Evernote is open, pressing those keys switches to Evernote instead
2) pressing those keys gives only two options, thus missing the "Match Destination Formatting" option that can sometimes be useful.